# Late Initialization: Field 'firebaseuser' has not been initialized

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```dart
//variables
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
late final Rx<User?> firebaseUser;

@override
void onReady(){
  firebaseUser = Rx<User?>(_auth.currentUser);
  firebaseUser.bindStream(_auth.userChanges());
  ever(firebaseUser, _setInitialScreen);
}
```

I'm following a tutorial from youtube and it shows an error like in this:
[image]

I already search for solution in google but all of it its not like what my code looks like. So what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

`firebaseUser` is declared as `late`, so if you try to access it before `onReady` is called you will get the error you are getting in the picture!

To fix this issue, consider ensuring that the `onReady` is called before you are accessing `firebaseUser` elsewhere in the code, or try to provide a default value for the field, such as null.

Comment: how to provide default value null to firebase user ?